# Deployment to Azure Blob Storage ends up with error

Tags: deployment, asp.net-core, continuous-integration, azure-blob-storage, appveyor

Trying to deploy artifacts ends up with the following error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

I'm running two scripts before and after I build the app in AppVeyor:

```
cd $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER\patch;
npm install;
node patch-project-json.js $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER\src\Project1\project.json $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION;
node patch-project-json.js $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER\src\Project2\project.json $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION;
node patch-project-json.js $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER\src\Project3\project.json $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION;


cd $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER
dotnet restore
```

and

```
dotnet publish .\src\Project1 --output $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER\deploy\Project1 --configuration Release --no-build;
dotnet publish .\src\Project2 --output $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER\deploy\Project2 --configuration Release --no-build;
dotnet publish .\src\Project3 --output $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER\deploy\Project3 --configuration Release --no-build
```

As you can see, I am using [this](http://codegists.com/snippet/javascript/patch-project-jsonjs_feodorfitsner_javascript) to set versions in `project.json` files based on the `$env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION`. I don't know if it's relevant information. So after successful build and publish, I want to upload an artifact to the blob storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I had typos in Deployment settings for `Storage access key` entry ;)